# Talend Select Query doesn't work properly

Tags: soql, query, talend

I'm trying to select the last created closed won opportunity for an account, this is my query used in talend:

```
SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate, AccountId, StageName
FROM Opportunity
WHERE StageName = 'Closed Won'
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But for the accounts that the last closed won opportunities were created before today the returned value is null, it only gets the opportunities created today.

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala If the account contains as a last one opportunity created for example last month, it doesn't return it, but if the last created opportunity is created today it returns it without problem.

Comment: Are you filtering based on AccountId in the above SOQL ? I dont see any issue from SOQL side

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala yes based on AccountId, I do it using talend mapping